# UTF-8 in Django, Umlauts doesent work with data from SQL Server

Tags: python-2.7, django-views

my problem is this:
i made a page with customer data out of a SQL Server database. my webpage is utf-8...
what i can see:

edit: it is not possible to show images if i am a new user... ^^

in the first "{{ rows_1 }}" you can see W\xe4denswil, but into a table it is not displayed. but why?
and in addition, it have to be Wädenswil (with german umlaut). i tried a lot of things to make my raw using utf-8. my last try was this:

rows_1 = unicode(cursor.fetchall(), 'utf-8')

but it means "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"

here is my used code (views from django):

```
  conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};CHARSET=UTF8;SERVER=MAURITIUS;DATABASE=baan5c;UID=portal;PWD=P0rtalReader')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT d.t_bpid, d.t_nama, a.t_namc, a.t_hono, a.t_pstc, a.t_name FROM ttccom100070 d, ttccom130070 a WHERE d.t_cadr = a.t_cadr AND (d.t_bpid = '%s')"%form)
    rows_1 = unicode(cursor.fetchall(), 'utf-8')

  return render_to_response('kundendaten.html', { 'rows_1': rows_1, 'rows_2': rows_2, 'rows_3': rows_3, 'current_date': now, 'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and here my html...:

```
<h2>Customer Data</h2>


{{ rows_1 }}
</fieldset>

<fieldset class= "field1">
<table border="1" class="name">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6">Customer Overview</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="CUSCos">Customer Number</th>
        <th class="CUSNam">Name</th>
        <th class="CUSStr">Street</th>
        <th class="CUSNr">Number</th>
        <th class="CUSZip">Zip Code</th>
        <th class="CUSCit">City</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in rows_1 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.3 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.4 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.5 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I use win7 32bit, python 2.7.3, django 1.4.1, html5 and css3

Comment: edit: the umlauts ("ä, ö, ü") from html itself are displayed correct...

Comment: hey, found some solution?

Comment: sorry doniyor, i was 1 month away, but i add now the answer... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was very easy, cause pyodbc has a function for that. The correct line is now:

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};CHARSET=UTF8;SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (x, y, w, p), unicode_results=True)

Its only this:

, unicode_results=True

You have to add...